# 'Wrong FS.. expected s3n://' when writing to Hive table from Spark 2.0

Tags: python, apache-spark, hive, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to insert data into a hive table with pyspark in Spark 2.0. Here's my code-

```
import pandas as pd
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

spark = SparkSession\
    .builder\
    .enableHiveSupport()\
    .appName("sparkApp")\
    .getOrCreate()


spark._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set('fs.defaultFS', 's3n')

data = pd.read_csv('s3n://some-path',sep = '\t',compression = 'gzip')
//some manipulation in data

data_sdf = spark.createDataFrame(data)
data_sdf.createOrReplaceTempView('data')

spark.sql(
'INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE schmea.my_table\     
PARTITION (col1,col2)\
select col1,col2,col3,col4 from data')
```

This results in an Exception-

```
App > pyspark.sql.utils.IllegalArgumentException: 'Wrong FS: s3://bucket/a-path, expected: s3n://bucket'
```

I am using Hive on EMR and the data files for Hive tables actually resides on S3. What should I do to avoid this exception?

Comment: It looks like you have a conflict b/w s3n and s3, and it seems your hive-conf and hdfs-conf has defaultFS as s3.

Comment: @AyanGuha Even if I don't set the defaultFS in the code to s3n, I get this error. In fact I added the line to set defaultFS in the code because I was getting the error. If there are conflicts in configs, is there a way to resolve that in code?